# HDD Health tool for CentOS?

Tags: centos, hard-drive, drive-failure

Does anyone know some good tool for checking HDD failure in Cent OS (Red Hat Systems) without downtime.
And tell me how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: smartmontools. How to use it:  Read the man page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smartmontools are good tools for this.

Install it with

`yum install smartmontools`

You can examine your drive with

`smartctl -t short /dev/sda`

More options you can find in man page.

Comment: I did 
`smartctl -d scsi -l selftest /dev/md2`
But I get this

`Standard Inquiry (36 bytes) failed [Invalid argument]
Retrying with a 64 byte Standard Inquiry
Standard Inquiry (64 bytes) failed [Invalid argument]
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.`

I need to unmount disk?!
I need it online...

Comment: /dev/md2 ?? this is some kindof raid device I think. With smartmon tools you can examine hardware discs not raid volumes.

Comment: When I do `df -h`
I get this:

`/dev/md2`
`/dev/md1`
`/usr/tmpDSK`

So I have these 3 partitions.
I have installed cPanel on my server, and sell shared hosting.
I have EX5 server with hetzner.de
this is info about hdd:

`Hard disks 2 x 750 GB SATA 3 Gb/s HDD
(Software-RAID 1)`
I noticed I have only 750 GB on `md2`, not 2x750 :(
On `md1` I have 440 mb that is boot partition...

Comment: @Luka, you need to read up on what logical volumes and RAID are. This is the correct answer, but you seem to be lacking some basic info.

Comment: @Luka if you have raid 1 on two disk 750GB then you will have only 750GB avaible for storage ... You can examine your underlying *physical* discs with smartctl to see if they are ok. Can you tell me what is your major problem with this RAID?

Comment: I want to use another 750 GB.How can I use it?
I do not care about smartctl, my new question is how to use another 750 gb, where is that another 750 gb?

Comment: @Luka you are using raid 1 ... In RAID 1 (mirroring without parity or striping), data is written identically to two drives, thereby producing a "mirrored set"; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID